# Uncaught TypeError: node.scrollIntoView is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, redux

- I am new to react.
- when I click section 1 content opens and if i move till the bottom of the section one content and after that if I click section 1 content closes.
- but I dont see section 2 after that I see section 3 since the screen moves upwards.
- how to retain the section 2 in our screen.
- to achieve that I am using this statement `node.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"});`
- but I am getting the error Uncaught `TypeError: node.scrollIntoView is not a function.` Can you guys tell me why I am getting
- providing the related code below

```or-tag-here
focusDiv() {
    var node = this.refs.theDiv;            
    node.scrollIntoView();
    console.log("node--->" + node);            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
var node = this.refs.theDiv;
```

With:

```
var node = this.refs.theDiv.getDOMNode();
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but still, section 2 is not coming to visible region...any idea ?? http://jsfiddle.net/b4L6kyg4/104/